# Form Validation in Date-Picker Field Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, validation, datepicker, dropdown, required

I have the following 2 fields which are for Date-Picker.

**In view:**

```html
<div class="form-line">                                
     <input type="text" id="iCaseFileDate" name="CaseFileDate" placeholder="Case File Date*" class="datepicker form-control" required/>                                
</div>

<div class="form-line">
     <input type="text" id="iHearingDate" name="HearingDate" placeholder="Hearing Date*" class="datepicker form-control" required/>                                
</div>
```

When i click the Submit button, it renders all fields of 'inputForm' very well with 'required' attribute like whenever i keep these fields empty then click submit the 'required' attribute works well. But after that if i select a date from Date-Picker field, it doesn't remove 'This field is required' for Case File Date & Hearing Date field.

**Javascript Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit_button').on('click', function () {
        $('#inputForm').valid()
    });
});

    $('#iCaseFileDate').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#iCaseFileDate').val()) {
            $('#iCaseFileDate').removeAttr("required");
        }
    });        

    $('#iHearingDate').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#iHearingDate').val()) {
            $('#iHearingDate').removeAttr("required");
        }
    });
```

**Submit Button Code:**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-success waves-light" onclick="saveData()">SAVE</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning waves-red" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

function saveData() {
            $("#inputForm").submit();
        }
        $("#inputForm").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            var $this = $(this);

            var frmValues = $this.serialize();
            var isValid = $("#inputForm").valid();
            if (isValid == false) {

            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/ClientInfo/Save',
                    data: frmValues
                })
                    .done(function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            alert(result.info);
                            clearInputFields();
                            $('#inputModal').modal('hide');
                            ReloadTable();
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (xhr) {
                        alert("error");
                    });
            }

        });
```

**[Image added for better clarification]**

[*Before filling any input field & clicking Submit Button*]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv4He.png)

[*After filling input field values, required message not removing for Case File Date & Hearing Date*]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQO2O.png)

Please help me solve this. I just want to show 'This field is required' message whenever these fields are empty and hide this message whenever these fields have value selected from datepickers.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code for the `submit_button`?

Comment: @Viqas code added for submit_button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear from your question, are you using model binding with MVC Razor view?

I think you can use below jquery code

```
$('#iCaseFileDate').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#iCaseFileDate').val().length>0) {
        $('#iCaseFileDate').removeAttr("required");
//comment
//Find the div containing validation message * the field is required* and remove it 
//like below
    $(this).next('.your_validation_message_div').remove(); 

    }
});        

$('#iHearingDate').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#iHearingDate').val().length>0) {
        $('#iHearingDate').removeAttr("required");
 //comment
//Find the div containing validation message * the field is required* and remove it 
//like below
    $(this).next('.your_validation_message_div').remove(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm. Can you please suggest me how i can again add that error message if these fields goes empty.
like:

$('#iCaseFileDate').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#iCaseFileDate').val().length>0) {
        $('#iCaseFileDate').removeAttr("required");
        $(this).next('.your_validation_message_div').remove(); 
    }
else{
       // Don't know how to re-add that error class //

       $(this).next('.error').add();
}
});

Comment: use  $('#iCaseFileDate').attr("required"); before if condition. like below

    $('#iCaseFileDate').on('change', function () {

    $(this).attr("required");
    if ($('#iCaseFileDate').val().length>0) {
        $('#iCaseFileDate').removeAttr("required");
//comment
//Find the div containing validation message * the field is required* and remove it 
//like below
    $(this).next('.your_validation_message_div').remove(); 

    }
});